# Synologie NAS - Using Symbolic Link with SFTP

Tags: permissions, ssh, symbolic-link, sftp, nas

In advance, sorry for the spelling errors. English isn't my first language, I will try to be as clear as possible.

I am trying to interconnect folder between them inside my NAS.

Example : I have a folder `Rock` where I put all the groups that do rock music, but since some groups don't only do rock; they sometimes try electro or rap styles, for example. So, I make a symbolic link to the folder `Rap` or `Electro` BUT I also want to have the possibility to go directly to the folder `Group`.

Here's an illustration of the paths:

**Main Folder:**

```
/volume/Group/
/volume/Music_Style/
```

**Subsidiary folder :**

```
/volume/Group/Linking_Park
/volume/Music_Style/Rock
```

**Use of symbolic link:**

```
/volume/Group/Linking_Park/Rock
/volume/Music_Style/Rock/Linking_Park
```

And from there I can go on infinitely.

But inside the NAS GUI, I cannot see the symbolic link although I can use it through SSH! So I thought "OK! I will use SFTP" and I can connect to the NAS fine and I can see the symbolic link just fine but every time I try to go inside the folder I get the following error:

> This location could not be displayed.
>
> You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of `<Name of the folder>`

The folder has mode 777 and my SSH account has the right to use the folder. The worst thing is that I can go inside the folder if I use my terminal but not through GUI.

So my first question is: **Does this type of hierarchy have a name?**

My main question is: **How can I fix this permission issue? Do I need to use another protocol to connect to the NAS?**

In advance, thank you.

Comment: What file system does your NAS use? Many NASes come with NTFS formatted disks, where symbolic links and file permissions have no meaning. However, some Synology models do support other file systems like ext4 and Btrfs.

Comment: The Filesystem that I use on /volume is "btrfs". So that good ?

Comment: Yes, Btrfs supports links and permissions just like ext4. So that is not the problem here.

Comment: I want to clarify something. The symbolic link will only be inside of the NAS.

Comment: Can you mount the NAS using Samba? (Also known as SMB or Cifs or even Windows Networking). Samba supports links.

Comment: I don't know a thing about Samba. I need to install it inside of the NAS or can i just it as a Client on my computer

Comment: You only need to install `cifs-utils` on your local computer and then you may see the NAS in Nautilus. I think Synology provides a Samba share out of the box.

Comment: Allow me to rephrase my suggestions as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The structure that you propose is very well possible with your setup.

Your Synology NAS comes with a GUI that has its limitations - apparently it can't handle links, whereas the underlying file system (Btrfs) can.

However, it is easy to access the NAS through Nautilus. Out of the box, the Synology device provides a SMB share. That means that it will turn up as a shared network folder on Windows systems without any more action from the Windows user. To see a SMB share in Ubuntu, you need to install `cifs-utils`.